# How to create a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, josso

I'm given a task to create a saml 2.0 identity provider and a service provider, but I'm totally blank on the concepts of single sign-on.

I have tried JOSSO but getting issues using it.

Is there any other way to create an identity provider. Can anyone please guide me on this topic.

Comment: Do you want to create your own Identity Provider (write an implementation) or you want to use an open source IdP server?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations. Personally, have a look at shibboleth, simpleSAMLphp (both free) or Auth0 (commercial)

Comment: I wanted to use an open source one. I tried JOSSO but unable to find much documentation, so was difficult to implement it.

Comment: Even if someone would help in implementing JOSSO it would be of great help

Comment: If you want to configure IDP and SP then You can use ADFS with Spring saml